# Semidefinite Integer Programming library

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to find an optimization framework that supports semidefinite programming (SDP) over integer variables. In my particular case, all the variables are 0-1, and it's not so much about optimization as finding a satisfying solution in the first place. (I know for a fact that there are solutions in the reals, I care about finding them in integers.) I'm having a hard time sifting through the various libraries out there, as they often don't indicate very well (imo) whether they support SDP or ILP. I also know that some might support both, but not necessarily be very good at using them together. I was hoping someone would have experience, thank you.

Oh, and academic licenses are fine (this is for academic work); ideally it would not be something that requires a commercial license.

Comment: I know of [SCIP](http://www.opt.tu-darmstadt.de/scipsdp/).

Comment: I eventually settled for SCIP, with DSDP for the SDP solving, and the SCIP-SDP plugin for repeated integer cuts. We'll see how it performs.

Comment: Maybe a SAT solver?